# How to get data from google analytics to MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How to get data from google analytics to MS SQL Server 2008?

Is there an API for that? Thanks!

i.e. Google Analytics API

Comment: Did you do a [web-search](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/integrate/) first?

Comment: There are serval custom SSIS tasks out there.   Here is another one. http://www.daimto.com/targit-google-analytics-ssis/  As far as I know this is the only one that works with 2005 , 2008 r2, 2012 and 2014. (Note I am the developer on that project)

Comment: If you want to go totally basic because you cant use SSIS I have a console application as well that just extracts the data to a CSV file you can use that to insert into SQL server.  http://www.daimto.com/tools/google-analytics-get/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SSIS GoogleAnalyticsSource](http://analyticssource.codeplex.com/)

> A SSIS Data Source Component for SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014
>   to load data from the Google Data API.

Also check [Google Analytics for SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services)](http://www.nikoport.com/2014/05/20/google-analytics-for-ssis-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: Question says says MS SQL Server 2008 doesn't it?

Comment: I must have missed something I checked both your links and they both appear to use SQL server 2012 and 2014, second one copies to Microsoft SQL Server\110 which is 2012.

Comment: @DaImTo:- Yes you are correct. My mistake. This one is good as well, http://www.outfox.com/excellentanalytics/

Comment: That's Microsoft Excel....  you need some coffee my friend :)  As far as I know mine is the only one that supports 2008 but if you find another one let me know.   I would love to compare :)